# Why does reprepro complain about the "all" architecture?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt, deb

I started setting up a deb repository today for some of our applications. Given that they are interpreted scripts, I went with "all" architecture (from `conf/distributions`):

```
Codename: lucid
Architectures: all
```

But reprepro will print a warning when I try to add a .deb to the repository:

```
WARNING: Distribution lucid contains an architecture called 'all'.
```

Now I wonder why it warns about that? What's the problem?

Comment: I don't know why it does that, but try removing the "Architectures" line. Does it work that way?

Comment: @Eduardo That results in Required field 'Architectures' expected (since line 1).
I also checked the source of reprepro. It explicitly checks for "all". But there is no comment in the source about thre reason either :(

Comment: Does it add the .deb anyway when it gives you the "all" error? It's only a warning, so I guess it should. Try using "amd64 all" instead to see if it only gives you a warning because it's the only one present.

Comment: @Eduardo No it doesn't create anything for "all". Also the "Packages" files for other architectures (like amd64) are created empty.

Comment: It sounds like a bug reports would be adequate. Does the tool have a `--verbose` switch you could use?

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. The source shows that it explicitly checks for the "all" architecture. So, most likely, there is something special (wrong) about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah ha! I finally just figured it out. This has been frustrating me for ages now.

If you specify your .deb (control file) as Architecture: all, then don't put anything into the reprepro distributions file other than the arch's that you want it to get put into.

Architectures: amd64 i386 ...

Comment: Had to figure that out too. The `all` packages are then available in all the architectures defined in `conf/distributions`.